# Como hacer una matriz de compracion en DQL o MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, dql

Quisiera crear una matriz con dos tablas en sql de la siguiente manera:

tengo una tabla que contiene los datos:

**id | nombre**
00 | formulario 0 
01 | formulario 1 
02 | formulario 2 
03 | formulario 3 
04 | formulario 4

otra tabla:

**id | nombre**
00 | persona.0 
01 | persona.1 
02 | persona.2 
03 | persona.3 
04 | persona.4

**id | persona | id formulario** 
00 | 00 | 02 
01 | 00 | 03 
02 | 00 | 04 
03 | 01 | 04 
04 | 02 | 02 
05 | 03 | 01 
06 | 03 | 04

y que el resultado de la consulta sea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***NOTA***:
Si para hacerlo con MySQL se consume mucho recurso que no es necesario y es mejor hacer una consulta basica y crear la matriz con el otro lenguaje, yo uso **PHP Y JQUERY**, enviando todo desde php al jquery por **JSON**

```
 create table formularios(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nombre varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table personas(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nombre varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table relacion(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
persona int,
formulario int,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (persona) REFERENCES personas(id),
FOREIGN KEY (formulario) REFERENCES formularios(id),
);
```

Comment: ¿Qué has probado por ahora? ¿Tienes código de partida? Si tuvieras en formato SQL los datos (`CREATE TABLE ...`, `INSERT INTO ...`) también nos ayudaría mucho para reproducir tu problema y darte código más exacto.

Comment: @OscarGarcia

create table formularios(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nombre varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table personas(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nombre varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table relacion(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
persona int,
formulario int,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (persona) REFERENCES personas(id),
FOREIGN KEY (formulario) REFERENCES formularios(id),
);

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregarlo a ella? Gracias.

Comment: @OscarGarcia listo

Comment: ¿Solucionaste el problema? ¿Te sirvió mi respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que deseas es obtener la información directamente en una consulta SQL entonces lo que necesitas es un `CROSS JOIN` que por cada formulario y persona devuelva un registro. El `LEFT JOIN` relacionará las dos primeras tablas dando `NULL` en sus campos si dicha relación no existe:

```
SELECT
  f.id fid,
  f.nombre formulario,
  p.id pid,
  p.nombre persona,
  IF(r.persona IS NULL, '', 'X') marca
FROM formularios f
CROSS JOIN personas p
LEFT JOIN relacion r
  ON r.formulario = f.id AND r.persona = p.id
ORDER BY
  f.id, p.id ASC
;
```

[Puedes probarlo en línea en este enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fcxenhx6VmuFHmFvPFsr9u/0)

Resultado:

```
fid formulario    pid  persona   marca
 0  formulario 0   0   persona.0   
 0  formulario 0   1   persona.1   
 0  formulario 0   2   persona.2   
 0  formulario 0   3   persona.3   
 0  formulario 0   4   persona.4   
 1  formulario 1   0   persona.0   
 1  formulario 1   1   persona.1   
 1  formulario 1   2   persona.2   
 1  formulario 1   3   persona.3   X
 1  formulario 1   4   persona.4   
 2  formulario 2   0   persona.0   X
 2  formulario 2   1   persona.1   
 2  formulario 2   2   persona.2   X
 2  formulario 2   3   persona.3   
 2  formulario 2   4   persona.4   
 3  formulario 3   0   persona.0   X
 3  formulario 3   1   persona.1   
 3  formulario 3   2   persona.2   
 3  formulario 3   3   persona.3   
 3  formulario 3   4   persona.4   
 4  formulario 4   0   persona.0   X
 4  formulario 4   1   persona.1   X
 4  formulario 4   2   persona.2   
 4  formulario 4   3   persona.3   X
 4  formulario 4   4   persona.4
```